# Url s are not storing properly in my table

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem in sql server , I am storing the url of selected image which is uploaded to a folder in same project. I am encountering a problem in storing the url of image into database. I can store the file name of 10 letters only. Suppose if i want to store the 11 letter word , it is getting stored upto 10 words only by skipping the last word.

I will try to explain more clearly 
First i am getting the file name from a fileupload to a hidden field , and appending the stored path before the file name like below.

```
         var File1 = $("#hdnImage").val();

        var Filepath = "/User_Registration1/upload/" + File1;
```

so if we take a example file name "userRegistration.jpg" , in this scenario it is storing like: /User_Registration1/upload/userRegist

suppose if i rename the file name to userRe.jpg then it is storing completely and showing image in image field. By the way my Filepath column size is nvarchar(300) in sql server .

Comment: Check the mysql definition of the column. It might be that you have VarChar(40) oder something similar which will then store at max 40 character, no matter what you provide.

Comment: It was tagged with mysql but description references sql server.

Comment: I already changed to sql server

Comment: How are you sending the value to the database? Could be a parameter for a query that's doing the truncating for you

Comment: I am using ajax post to save the values to database

Comment: @eXOdu5 sp_help TABLE_NAME gave me the Column Length 1000 nvarchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by changing my Column data Type to Nchar(50) or depending on your url char length.